# Where should I start a coroutine which should be called every time collision is detected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a new project MOBA like game and I came a cross problem which I just can not find a solution for. I am pretty sure the problem is where I call the coroutine. Right now I am calling the function in `Update` that checks for collision and starts the coroutine if it detects something. The coroutine starts but it never ends. I tried to find a solution in events, functions, stopping the coroutine manually but I just can not find solve the problem. All feedback is welcome, thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

- Where I call the function

  ```
    private void Update()
    {
        CheckForCollision();
    }
  ```
- What is in the function

  ```
    private void CheckForCollision()
    {
        Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(position, scale, layerMask);

        foreach (Collider c in colliders)
        {
            c.TryGetComponent<PlayerController>(out PlayerController player);
            StartCoroutine (player.ApplyDebuff(player.speed, 30, 5, debuffValue => 
            player.speed = debuffValue, originalValue => player.speed = originalValue));
            player.TakeDamage(50);

            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
  ```
- What is in the Coroutine

  ```
    public IEnumerator ApplyDebuff(float stat, float percentage, float duration, 
    System.Action<float> OnWhileAction, System.Action<float> AfterWaitAction)
    {
        float originalValue = stat;
        float timeStamp = Time.time;

        while (Time.time < timeStamp + duration)
        {
            float debuffValue = originalValue - (percentage / 100 * originalValue);
            OnWhileAction(debuffValue);

            yield return null;
        }
        AfterWaitAction(originalValue);
    }
  ```

Comment: I'm rather confused by what your code is trying to do. You first start a coroutine, then destroy the `gameObject` on which the script is attached, therefore also destroying the coroutine. That just seems wrong on principle. Either you need to keep the script alive or the coroutine should not be running on the `gameObject` your script is attached to, but rather on the one that was collided with

Comment: Collisions by default trigger an event. What is wrong with using the predefined option?

Comment: I did actually think about that. And it looks like destroying the object was the problem. And to answer why I am not using `OnTigger` methods I just do not know how to detect layers using it so I find it easier to use custom method.